# Get categories with posts that contain certain tag

Tags: wordpress

We have 10 categories, say A, B, C, D, etc

We have 1 tag, say `tag`

The function `get_categories` will get all categories that have posts in them (by default), but what we need is that same function, only we need to get only categories with posts that have a certain tag.

So category `A` has 5 posts with tag `tag`, Category `B` has none, Category `C` has 3. Then I want to see `A` and `C` in this list.

Is it possible to filter `get_categories` by tag?

## Update 1

Tried

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'tag',
                    'value'   => 'my-tag-slug',
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        ) );
```

Also tried with Tag ID. It's the standard post categories and tags that I'm using.

Answer (score 4):

Use get_terms() instead and make use of the meta_query args you can use: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Something like:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'tag',
            'value'   => 'tag',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

This does differ depending on what version of WordPress you are using - so check the documentation.

Look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for more on the 'meta_query' part of the arguments.

**UPDATE**

Try something like this (note change {tag-slug} to your required tag slug

```
// Get the categories
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
) );

// Loop through them
foreach($terms as $term) {
  // Get the posts in that category with the required tag
  $args = array(
    'category_name'    => $term->name,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => '{tag-slug}'
        )
    )
  );
  $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

  foreach ($posts_array as $value) {
    // save what you need here - maybe an array for each category with the posts so you can run a count on them?
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. I get an empty array. I'm on 4.5.1 so your code is fine. I also can't find anything related to tags on https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query or on Google otherwise...

Comment: Could you show your version of my code - so I can see what your category and meta names are. My example won't work if you just copy and paste it as is.

Comment: Ahh you updated as I was typing - so you have a meta field called "tag" and you have added a value under this called "my-tag-slug" is that correct? Are you just using the default WordPress Category and Tag?

Comment: No, not a meta field. We're using the actual `tag` system of Wordpress

Comment: Delving deeper it looks like this wont work... the best plan is to get the posts by category and by tag - looping through each category.... if that makes sense?

Comment: Updated my answer - will need some work but should put you in the right direction